# How to create my nginx.conf

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, dockerfile

The problem is that the API and the frontend aren't linked.
I'm able to use the `--link` command when I start the nginx container. But I stil need to edit my nginx.conf.

At the moment I have

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

        upstream node-app {
              least_conn;
              server nodejs:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;

        }

        server {
              listen 80;

              location / {
                proxy_pass http://node-app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
        }
}
```

My nodejs container has the `--name` nodejs and its running on port 8888 (`-p 8888:8888`)
It's dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/www
WORKDIR /usr/src/www

# copy
COPY node_modules /usr/src/www/node_modules
COPY gulpfile.js /usr/src/www/gulpfile.js
COPY gulp.config.js /usr/src/www/gulp.config.js
COPY server.js /usr/src/www/server.js 

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

I start it by performing:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --name nodejs localhost:5000/test/nodejs-image:1
```

I'm able to visit my api on localhost:8888/api

This is the dockerfile of nginx (dist is created after npm install etc. for angular)

```
FROM nginx
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html/dist
```

When I just perform:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name nginx localhost:5000/test/nginx-image:1
```

I'm able to visit my static files on localhost:80/dist/...

But I have to link the two containers + change the nginx.conf:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name nginx --link nodejs:nodejs -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf localhost:5000/test/nginx-image:1
```

My server.js contains stuff like:

```
app.post('/api/login', requestProxy({
  url: xxx + "/login"
}));
```

Can someone fix my nginx.conf or is there another fault?

Comment: You expose 8080 and run with 8888, is that your problem? Did you try to `docker exec` into your nginx and see in /etc/hosts if nodejs is populated (try ping nodejs) ?

Answer (score 0):

One Changes:
In your nginx.conf, change *proxy_pass http://node-app* to **proxy_pass http://nodejs:8888**

When you link your conatiner *"--link nodejs:nodejs"* docker creates and entry in /etc/hosts file with "conatiner_name container_ip", so you can reach (ping) linked container with its name.